# Magento2 having Issue in language installation "Duplicated translation is found, but it is not allowed"

Tags: magento2, language, translate

I am trying to install German language pack and its showing me error
' Duplicated translation is found, but it is not allowed '

Commands:

wget https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-german-language-pack/raw/master/de_DE.csv

```
php bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace de_DE.csv de_DE

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

when I run the third command the error is shown. Please help me to fix this error.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: @Teja bhagavan Kollepara Why are you editing all the post.. if you know the answer post here..

Comment: Having the same issue for de-DE and es-AR. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You have to define `'-d'` for allow duplicate translation.

use `i18n:pack -m replace -d de_DE.csv` de_DE command for allow

duplicate translation  instead of `i18n:pack -m replace de_DE.csv de_DE`

here -d => use for allow duplicate translation

Now Your command will be

```
php bin/magento i18n:pack -m replace -d de_DE.csv de_DE

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

its working for me.